# Applying Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I am currently working on the state transition of a system execution cycle and applying some mathematical computations over it to get various other values.

Please refer the diagram below to understand the state flow diagram of the system.
[image]

The probability matrix of the following transition is as follows,

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
    0&  .5&    0&    0&    0&   0&   0&   0&   0&  .5\\
    0&   0&  .33&  .33&  .33&   0&   0&   0&   0&   0\\
    0&   0&    0&    0&    0&  .5&  .5&   0&   0&   0\\
   .5&   0&   .5&    0&    0&   0&   0&   0&   0&   0\\
    1&   0&    0&    0&    0&   0&   0&   0&   0&   0\\
    0&   0&    0&    0&    0&   0&   0&  .5&  .5&   0\\
    1&   0&    0&    0&    0&   0&   0&   0&   0&   0\\
    0&   0&    0&    0&    0&   0&   0&   1&   0&   0\\
    0&   0&    0&    0&    0&   0&   0&  .5&   0&  .5\\
    0&   0&    0&    0&    0&   0&   0&   0&   0&   1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now my need is that I want to calculate the probability of state transition from $S20 \to S40$. I am using Bayes formula for calculating it.

$$\operatorname{Pr}(S40|S20) = \frac{\operatorname{Pr}(S20|S40) \operatorname{Pr}(S40)}{P(S20)}$$

Now I need assistance in,

1. Confirming that I am using the right approach.
2. How will I evaluate $\operatorname{Pr}(S20|S40)$? For all the other values can be referred from the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your matrix orders the events in the following way: 
$$\{S10,S15,S20,S21,S22,S30,S31,S40,S41,S41\}.$$

Then, the fact that 
$$\operatorname{Pr}(S20)=\operatorname{Pr}(S15\to S20)=0.33,$$
can be simply read off the transition matrix. 
Since $S40$ only happens if $S20$ happened first, it follows that
$$\operatorname{Pr}(S20|S40)=1.$$
Finally, 
$$\operatorname{Pr}(S40)=\operatorname{Pr}(S15\to S20)\operatorname{Pr}(S20\to S30)\operatorname{Pr}(S30\to S40)=0.33*0.5*0.5=0.0825,$$
and
$$\operatorname{Pr}(S40|S20)=\frac{0.0825}{0.33}=0.25.$$